# Cannot get autocomplete to work in CodeIgniter - thoughts?

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery-autocomplete

I have a form in which a user can type the name of a video game. What I'm trying to do is set up an autocomplete in a field with both a name and ID of "gameTitle." The autocomplete is to pull from a field called "title" from a database table called "aararity."

I used [the guide on this blog](http://www.jamipietila.fi/codeigniter-and-autocomplete-with-jquery/) as my paradigm.

First, I know for autocomplete to work, you need to have this in `config/config.php` and I do:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
```

At the top of my view, I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
$( "#gameTitle" ).autocomplete({ // the field I want to autocomplete is called gameTitle
source: function(request, response) {
$.ajax({ url: "",
data: { term: $("#gameTitle").val()},
dataType: "json",
type: "POST",
success: function(data){
response(data);
}
});
},
minLength: 2
});
});
});
```

Here’s the “suggestions” function in my controller (the “title” referred to in $row->title refers to the “title” field in the database table I’m trying to pull from):

```
function suggestions()
{
            $this->load->model('usergames_model');
            $term = $this->input->post('term',TRUE);

            if (strlen($term) < 2) break;

            $rows = $this->autocomplete_model->GetAutocomplete(array('keyword' => $term));

            $json_array = array();
            foreach ($rows as $row)
            array_push($json_array, $row->title);

            echo json_encode($json_array);
}
```

Now, here’s what I added into the model:

```
function GetAutocomplete($options = array())
{
     $this->db->select('title');
     $this->db->like('title', $options['keyword'], 'after');
     $query = $this->db->get('aararity');
     return $query->result();
}
```

Basically, when I run the form, there’s no autocompletion whatsoever. I’m thinking the `$options[keyword]` parameter might be the problem; I pretty much copied that right from the aforementioned blog, and I’m guessing that might be a vague placeholder used by the author.

What am I missing?

Comment: what is the `url` are you posting to. and who said that csrf should be off. and what error are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any error at all; I'm just not getting an autocomplete. The blog I mentioned in my original post says that yo uneed to turn off CSRF for autocomplete. I've seen several other sources say that as well. The URL I'm posting to?? How do you mean??

Comment: Oh...what I'm posting to is the "suggestions" function of my controller called "usergames".

Comment: first, the url seems empty to me `url = ''`. second you can add the csrf. but now, how come you are getting no error. no error means that the source of your auto-complete is empty. have you tried to see what results are coming form your db without autocomplete?

Comment: NOTHING comes from my DB...just tried. Weird.

Comment: Oh...as for the url = '' thing, I don't know what happened...stackoverflow must have cut that out in transit because that line should read $.ajax({ url: "<?php echo site_url('usergames/suggestions'); ?>",

Answer (score 0):

OMG, I can't believe it...I figured it out...

suggestions() was trying to call a nonexistent model called "autocomplete_model" -- I forgot to change that to "usergames_model"!!!!

Now it works wonderfully!